# jQuery post function not working with php post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I have a problem with my post. I get the values from html input:

```
$('#submit-login-modal').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var login = $('#input-login-modal').val();
    var senha = $('#input-senha-modal').val();

    makeLogin(login, senha);
});
```

Then I try to post to one of my php pages that will handle the information, but I'm getting no answer form the php. I even tried to console.log inside the function, but no response.

This is the function:

```
function makeLogin(login, password) {
$.post("requestHandler.php", {"action":"login", 
                              "nome" : login, 
                              "senha"  : password}, 
    function(data) {
        console.log("oi");
        console.log(data);
    }, 
"json");}
```

I also verified that I have no php errors. I thought it could be a path error, but the .js and the .php are together in the same folder.

Comment: And what you see on the network tab?

Comment: Remove json and do print_r($_POST) in requestHandler.php and then see what is the log.

Comment: The thing is that your PHP script is not returning a valid JSON string, which causes the callback function halt. Abraços!

Comment: Also are you binding $('#submit-login-modal').click in an event like document ready ? If not then it wouldn't trigger your function.

Comment: I did as Samosa said and found the error. The problem of getting non documented work from another dev. Its a internal error with nothing to do with de JS. Thanks for the help and sorry for the waste of time.